# Lexical Text Editor: What should I save to the database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lexicaljs

I'm building a rich text editor for a question and answer site.

As far as I know Lexical lets us get output data to JSON, JSON string, HTML, Markdown and others.

Based on the recommended best practices, what data should I save to a MySQL or MongoDB database?

This is a new site.

Comment: The reason Lexical has options is because you have options. "Best practices" are best in different situations. That aside, please don't ask for recommendations (opinion-based question) on StackOverflow; take a moment to read [ask].

Comment: @code I have no specific conditions. Thank you for reminding.

Comment: If I may suggest, you might consider JSON, as it's not very complicated to work with and is easy to convert back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. JSON (type string) or JSON (type JSON) on MySQL? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: Either, I guess. Probably JSON string so it's easier to store in the DB?

Comment: @code If we keep the lexical JSON Node, what if we switch to a different editor one day?

Comment: Then you would do HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is recommended by Lexical to store a JSON string for the Lexical editor state

```
// Handler to store content
const onSubmit = () => {
  await saveContent(JSON.stringify(editor.getEditorState()));
}
```

https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/editor-state

Then you can serialize/deserialized as described here: https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/serialization#lexical---json

Comment: "... recommended by Lexical to store a JSON ...", Is there a sentence in the documentation that states this? Can you provide the link.

Comment: @R.M.Reza, dgeorg said "It looks like", not "they say" nor "they recommend". It is, in fact, shown as an example in the Lexical official documentation. Just recommend modifying the sentence to prevent confusion. Hope you have a good time coding :)

Answer (score 0):

After all, json data is a string with a specific predefined structure, you can convert any json to string using JSON.stringify(), and revert it from syring to json format with JSON.parse()

Comment: How does this address the question?